# How to manipulate Manifest file with maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, ear, maven-ear-plugin

I have an EAR file built with maven. The EAR contains several jars and I need to add a line in the manifest file for just one of these jars. I know of the maven-jar-plugin option (manifestEntries) but this is good for a single standalone jar, not one that is inside an EAR.

Answer (score 4):

If you take a deeper look into [maven-ear-plugin configuration](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/ear-mojo.html) you will find the archive configuration part which is exactly intended for such purposes.

This can be added to the configuration of the maven-ear-plugin:

```
<archive>
  <addMavenDescriptor/>
  <compress/>
  <forced/>
  <index/>
  <manifest>
    <addClasspath/>
    <addDefaultImplementationEntries/>
    <addDefaultSpecificationEntries/>
    <addExtensions/>
    <classpathLayoutType/>
    <classpathMavenRepositoryLayout/>
    <classpathPrefix/>
    <customClasspathLayout/>
    <mainClass/>
    <packageName/>
  </manifest>
  <manifestEntries>
    <key>value</key>
  </manifestEntries>
  <manifestFile/>
  <manifestSections>
    <manifestSection>
      <name/>
      <manifestEntries>
        <key>value</key>
      </manifestEntries>
    <manifestSection/>
  </manifestSections>
  <pomPropertiesFile/>
</archive>
```

Which gives you any opportunity you need.

Comment: If you look carefully at my question you'll see i need to edit the manifest of one specific jar, the option you suggested edits all the manifest files of all the jars in the EAR.

Comment: Oups.. Does that mean you like to manipulate an existing JAR ? Is this project which creates this jar in your hand ?

Comment: Than you have to go into that project and change the configuration for the maven-jar-plugin in the same as i described for the maven-ear-plugin.

Comment: I have the maven jar plugin defined at a central pom file used by other projects, if i put it in the pom of the specific project i want, it works but it packs it as a different jar and not as part of the EAR.

Comment: Have deployed it and used it in your ear build ?

Answer (score 1):

I think can you look at the [`maven-shade-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/index.html) and use the [`ManifestResourceTransformer`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#ManifestResourceTransformer) to change the manifest for the jar.

Comment: thank you but, as it turns out, I currently don't need it ,but if I'll need it in the future I'll be sure to check it out.