# How to add manifest.mf parameters in Intellij to a JavafX Maven project?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When i compile my JavaFX maven project, Intellij creates a Jar file and automatically includes Manifest.MF with all the dependencies on the classpath and other default parameters.
But i want to add a splash screen image to it (SplashScreen-Image: META-INF/loading.png).

How do i change the manifest without having to do it manually after ?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10704543/how-to-manipulate-manifest-file-with-maven

Comment: Thanks, please add it as an answer so i can accept it!